# follow up message

Tags: questions, tone

I am asking an expert for a piece of advise, I have wrote the message, but he did not answer. I am going to write a follow up. Which one is more tolerant and correct:

1) Hi Ann! How's it going? Did you have time to go through my message?

2) Hi Ann! How's it going? Did you get a chance to look my message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second one is missing the word *at* after *look*:

> Hi Ann! How's it going? Did you get a chance to look **at** my message?

Once that is fixed, both choices are OK. The second one is maybe slightly more polite since looking at a message is simple but "going through" sounds like more detailed work. I think you are just trying to ask if she has started considering your message, not whether she has analyzed it in detail.

Comment: And how does the poster or anyone else know whether you are right or wrong when all you are doing is expressing an opinion? If you really think you should answer questions like this which are obviously unsuitable for this site and will soon be closed, then you need to argue your point or justify it with external sources. But the game is clearly not worth the candle for this English Learners question.

Comment: Why is its unsuitable David?

Comment: @David - Sorry, I guess I assumed that migrated questions will have their answers migrated. Just trying to help the OP. I agree it's a better fit for ell.stackexchange.com

Comment: @David - I don't think it's unreasonable for a simple learning question to have a simple unsourced answer from a fluent or native speaker of English. If there is disagreement among fluent speakers, it would certainly raise the issue of needing additional sources. Do you have more of a problem with my answer to the question or with the question being on this site?

Comment: "English Language & Usage Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts." Why are you encouraging misuse of the site by answering "simple learning questions"?

Comment: @David - I can't vote to migrate, but I've flagged it for migration